# Error when playing an audio file from a URL

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
String url = "http://23.101.29.94:1111/text1.mp3";
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
```

When it run:

```
2019-11-04 20:55:31.221 13816-13816/com.example.loginlogout E/MediaPlayerNative: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0xe9a85440)
2019-11-04 20:55:31.221 13816-13816/com.example.loginlogout E/MediaPlayerNative: error (-38, 0)
2019-11-04 20:55:31.235 13816-13816/com.example.loginlogout E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
```

but this url (http://23.101.29.94:1111/text1.mp3) run well in browser, How I fix that

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `mediaPlayer.start()` in the `onPrepared` method by using a listener. 
Listeners can be attached simply by

```
mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried, but it's not work

Comment: can you try with https instead of http

Comment: I use this URL: http://23.101.29.94:1111/cau2 , but same error

Comment: and also do not forget to ask for the permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @TríPhan do you get the same error with onPrepared listener?